# unwillingToPerform ldap3 useAccountControl change

Tags: python, ssl, active-directory, ssl-certificate, ldap3

I am   using   ldap3 module in python to  create  and disable users  in AD  in python. When I   create a   user using the   following   code,

```
from ldap3  import *
import ssl
tls_configuration = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, 
version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
tls_configuration.validate = ssl.CERT_NONE
s = Server('xxxxxx:389',use_ssl=False, get_info=ALL)
c=Connection(s,user='x\Administrator',password='x',
check_names=True,lazy=False,
raise_exceptions=False)
c.open()
c.bind()
c.add('cn=SubhasisB,ou=gssd users,dc=adldap,dc=com','User')
```

the   users  created using the  above command are showing  disabled with   the  attribute  userAccountControl    set to 546    with no password. When I   try to modify the   attribute   to 512   to  enable the   user   I get the   error

```

> c.modify('cn=SubhasisB,ou=gssd users,dc=adldap,dc=com', {'unicodePwd': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['xxxxx'])]})
>   False
>
> > c.result
> >     {'result': 53, 'description': 'unwillingToPerform', 'dn': '', 'message': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A11E5, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\x00', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'modifyResponse'}```

getting the   same   error for

`c.modify('cn=SubhasisB,ou=gssd users,dc=adldap,dc=com', {'userAccountControl': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['512'])]})`

However if  I manually  create a  user in the  Windows  server   I am able  to disable  it  by setting the userAccountControl  to 514   using ldap3.

Comment: I am partially  able to achieve my task  by   doing  the following:

`>>> c.modify('cn=SubhasisB,ou=gssd users,dc=adldap,dc=com', {'userAccountControl': [(MODIFY_REPLACE,['544'])]})
True`

Comment: Need   help  with setting password   using ldap3
`>>> USER_DN="adldap\SubhasisB"
>>> NEWPWD="some_complex_password_that_works_manually in AD"
>>> CURRENTPWD=None
>>> print (ldap3.extend.microsoft.modifyPassword.ad_modify_password(c, USER_DN, NEWPWD, CURREENTPWD,  controls=None))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ldap3' is not defined`